# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int' when multiplying using asterisk (*)

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, machine-learning

In the `HuBMAPDataset` class, I set `sz` using `self.sz = reduce*sz`. My code raised unsupported operand type error.

```
reduce = 4
class HuBMAPDataset:
    def __init__(self, idx, fold, train=True, tfms=None):
        self.data = rasterio.open(os.path.join(DATA,idx+'.tiff'), transform = identity,num_threads='all_cpus')
        ids = pd.read_csv(LABELS).id.astype(str).values
        kf = KFold(n_splits=nfolds,random_state=SEED,shuffle=True)
        ids = set(ids[list(kf.split(ids))[fold][0 if train else 1]])
        self.fnames = [fname for fname in os.listdir(TRAIN) if fname.split('_')[0] in ids]
        self.train = train
        self.tfms = tfms
        if self.data.count != 3:
            subdatasets = self.data.subdatasets
            self.layers = []
            if len(subdatasets) > 0:
                for i, subdataset in enumerate(subdatasets, 0):
                    self.layers.append(rasterio.open(subdataset))
        self.shape = self.data.shape
        self.reduce = reduce
        self.sz = reduce*sz
        self.pad0 = (self.sz - self.shape[0]%self.sz)%self.sz
        self.pad1 = (self.sz - self.shape[1]%self.sz)%self.sz
        self.n0max = (self.shape[0] + self.pad0)//self.sz
        self.n1max = (self.shape[1] + self.pad1)//self.sz
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.fnames), self.n0max*self.n1max
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        fname = self.fnames[idx]
        img = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(os.path.join(TRAIN,fname)), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        mask = cv2.imread(os.path.join(MASKS,fname),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        if self.tfms is not None:
            augmented = self.tfms(image=img,mask=mask)
            img,mask = augmented['image'],augmented['mask']
        n0,n1 = idx//self.n1max, idx%self.n1max
        x0,y0 = -self.pad0//2 + n0*self.sz, -self.pad1//2 + n1*self.sz
        p00,p01 = max(0,x0), min(x0+self.sz,self.shape[0])
        p10,p11 = max(0,y0), min(y0+self.sz,self.shape[1])
        img = np.zeros((self.sz,self.sz,3),np.uint8)
        if self.data.count == 3:
            img[(p00-x0):(p01-x0),(p10-y0):(p11-y0)] = np.moveaxis(self.data.read([1,2,3],
                window=Window.from_slices((p00,p01),(p10,p11))), 0, -1)
        else:
            for i,layer in enumerate(self.layers):
                img[(p00-x0):(p01-x0),(p10-y0):(p11-y0),i] =\
                  layer.read(1,window=Window.from_slices((p00,p01),(p10,p11)))
        if self.reduce != 1:
            img = cv2.resize(img,(self.sz//reduce,self.sz//reduce),
                             interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        #check for empty imges
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        h,s,v = cv2.split(hsv)
        if (s>s_th).sum() <= p_th or img.sum() <= p_th:
            #images with -1 will be skipped
            return img2tensor((img/255.0 - mean)/std), -1, img2tensor(mask)
        else: return img2tensor((img/255.0 - mean)/std), idx, img2tensor(mask)


for fold in range(nfolds):
    for idx,row in tqdm(df_sample.iterrows(),total=len(df_sample)):
        idx = str(row['id'])
        ds_t = HuBMAPDataset(idx, fold=fold, train=True, tfms=get_aug())
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_33/1067530021.py in <module>
      3     for idx,row in tqdm(df_sample.iterrows(),total=len(df_sample)):
      4         idx = str(row['id'])
----> 5         ds_t = HuBMAPDataset(idx, fold=fold, train=True, tfms=get_aug())
      6         ds_v = HuBMAPDataset(idx, fold=fold, train=False)
      7         data = ImageDataLoaders.from_dsets(ds_t,ds_v,bs=bs,num_workers=NUM_WORKERS,pin_memory=True).cuda()

/tmp/ipykernel_33/3421423662.py in __init__(self, idx, fold, train, tfms)
     25         self.shape = self.data.shape
     26         self.reduce = reduce
---> 27         self.sz = reduce*sz
     28         self.pad0 = (self.sz - self.shape[0]%self.sz)%self.sz
     29         self.pad1 = (self.sz - self.shape[1]%self.sz)%self.sz

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'
```

`df_sample` (as dictionary)

```
df_sample.to_dict()
{'id': {0: 10078}, 'rle': {0: '12 34'}}
```

Comment: What is `reduce`?  Nothing in the code you show defines it.

Comment: Other instance attributes like `self.train` are set from `__init__` arguments.  `reduce` is missing.  Its uses in this class are not consistent with it being a function.  Either you wrote a lot of code without testing it, or borrowed from someplace without understanding what's going on.

Comment: Is that `reduce=4` that you added in the question edit,  in the original code (that produced the error), or something you tried latter?  The `ipykernel_33` in the traceback indicates that you are using a jupyter notebook.  It you don't run cells in the correct order, you can get errors like this, where one time `reduce` is the `functools` builtin, and another time a simple number. You need to clean up how `reduce` and `self.reduce` is set and used in this class.  Taking it from a `global` increases the chances of errors like this.

Answer (score -1):

'reduce' is a function from functools. You multiply a function with an int. That's why you got the error.
You can reproduce this error by the following simple code:

```
from functools import reduce
c = reduce * 3
```

Comment: How do I rectify the error?

Comment: You need to find out where `reduce` is coming from, then rename it.